# How to change direction of horizontal scrolling with Smooth Div Scroll?

Tags: jquery, direction, smooth-scrolling

I'm using [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) into a page and it works correctly (thanks to Thomas Kahn! :P)

I need only the mousewheelScrolling, and the problem is the direction: with scroll-up the content goes left and vice-versa, but this is innatural. I tried to use the mousewheelScrolling option with a negative number (as reported [here](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html)), but it doesn't work.
(It's strange that there are two options with the same name... is it possible that the second option have a different name?)

How can I invert scrolling direction?

I'm sorry for bad English :D

Thanks in advance for support. :)

Comment: UPDATE
I got it: the real property name for speed and direction was mousewheelScrollingStep. Thanks the same!

Comment: If you answered the question, please provide the solution below for others who also may have this problem in the future.

Comment: The solution is to set the property mousewheelScrollingStep to a negative number.

Comment: I could change the default in the next release, I just wasn't sure what was the most natural behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know - the scrolling direction has been changed in the latest version, just like you suggested. So mousewheel scrolling up now makes the scroller scroll left and mousewheel scrolling down makes the scroller scroll right. Thanks for your input regarding this!

I've also extended the mousewheelScrolling option to give you better control over the mousewheel events. Some mice have both vertical and horizontal mousewheel scrolling and now you decide which events the scroller should listen to.

You'll find [more info on the extended option here](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/options.html#mousewheelScrolling).